# Why does AbortOnConnectFail option does not work well with Redis Sentinel Connection in ConnectionMultiplexer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

Why does `AbortOnConnectFail` option in `ConfigurationOption` for `ConnectionMultiplexer` from `StackExchange.Redis` still makes the connection multiplexer to throw Sentinel exception connection errors like:

`Unhandled exception. StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: Sentinel: Failed connecting to configured master for service: mymaster`

Is there a good way to configure it so that in case it fails, it will not throw the exception an just retry?

Here is an example of how I connect to Redis:

```cs
var redisConnectionConfiguration = new ConfigurationOptions
      {
        ClientName = "Foo",
        EndPoints =
          {
              { redisConfigSection["Host"] },
          },
        Password = redisConfigSection["Password"],
        AllowAdmin = true,
        AbortOnConnectFail = false,
        ReconnectRetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(2000),
        ServiceName = isRedisSentinelEnabled ? "mymaster" : null,
      };

var redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionConfiguration, Console.Out);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use ConnectionMultiplexer deal with disconnection, you can [check my smaple code](https://github.com/Jason446620/redis-mvc-core-master).

[Reconnecting with Lazy pattern](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#reconnecting-with-lazyt-pattern)

> We have seen a few rare cases where StackExchange.Redis fails to reconnect after a connection blip (for example, due to patching). Restarting the client or creating a new ConnectionMultiplexer will fix the issue. Here is some sample code that still uses the recommended Lazypattern while allowing apps to force a reconnection periodically. Make sure to update code calling into the ConnectionMultiplexer so that they handle any ObjectDisposedException errors that occur as a result of disposing the old one.

Comment: I will check it out and let you know if I was able to use this for my problem